# Can I pass JSON data via hidden field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a form that is built from an AJAX response within a for loop. One of the vars is a JSON obeject that I need to pass alongside the form fields into a 'step-2' submit. I am using something like:

```
for (var i = 0; i < filteredResults.length; i++) {
   var id = filteredResults[i].ID;
   var obj = filteredResults[i].jsonData; //this is the json obj I would like to pass when the form
                                          // is submitted
   var someform = "";
   var someform += "<form id='someform' class='someform' method='post'>";
   // some input fields built from the vars
   // some hidden fields build from the vars
   var someform += "</form>";
   $("#some-div-on-my-page").append(someform);
```

On form submit, the .vals are assigned to vars, but how can I pass the JSON obj also? This is not something I can pass in a hidden field, right?

```
$(document).on('submit', '#my_form', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   hidden_field1 = $("#hidden_field").val();
   hidden_field2 = $("#hidden_field2").val();
   //----- how can I pass the json obj?
   //----- blah blah blah
```

Comment: Stringify on the way in. Parse on the way out. But be very careful about what you’re doing here... this is extremely unsafe html / JavaScript. If this will ever be a real site it’s a script injection waiting to happen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add JSON to a hidden field like this..

```
<input type="hidden" value="{"name":"John"}">
```

Comment: probably going to need a name field on that input too so it has a var name in POST

Comment: I ran JSON.stringify on my obj and passed it the the hidden field value and on the other side of the AJAX I ran JSON.parse so I could loop through it for the next step of the form.